# Errno::EPERM (Operation not permitted FILE_PATH) when uploading image with Rails, Carrierwave, Amazon EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, permissions, carrierwave

I am getting an error in production that is preventing me from uploading an image to Amazon EC2 using Rails and Carrierwave.

The application works perfectly on my local development server, but in production I am getting this error

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6319ms

Errno::EPERM (Operation not permitted - /FILE/PATH/TO/IMAGE/DESTINATION):
```

I checked to make sure that the destination file has all the correct permissions. It is the upload directory, which I made sure that the entire directory was readable, writable and executable by anyone.

```
 ** [] lrwxrwxrwx.  1 foo rvm   50 Oct  3 10:53 uploads
```

Anyone know whats going on?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this? I'm getting the sane error.

Comment: I just answered. Are you using multistage extension for you app? That was the root of our problem

Comment: I'm not using multistage extension, but I had a similar permissions problem and solution. The app was running in passenger as "nobody", and needed to be running as our custom user, who had permission to read/write on the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was caused by a permissions issue. Our rails app uses Amazon EC2, Capistrano for deployment and multistage extension for production and staging environments.

Before we moved to multistage extension one of the contributors owned the entire rails app, lets call him "foo". Once we implemented multistage, we decided to move the entire app to use a global user called "appuser". The problem is that many of the uploads were still owned by foo. This was causing write issues.

Changing ownership of all uploads to the proper user and group fixed the issue.

Comment: FileUtils.chown 'appuser','appuser', file_path          <== this command also will not change the ownership to appuser. it also will show the "Errno::EPERM " permission issue when we are performing this action from another user "foo"

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the permissions of carrierwave's cache_path? By default it's public/uploads/tmp/.

Have you checked carrierwave's config.permissions and config.directory_permissions? They default to 0666 and 0777 respectively, and this may or may not be sufficient to permit uploads depending on how your server is set up.