# Permission Denied error when uploading to local filesystem via paperclip gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, permission-denied

I've used paperclip in the past with AWS S3 storage, but with this project I'm trying to reduce external dependencies. I'd like to save uploaded images to the public/assets directory, for immediate use (skirting asset pipeline). Here's the error I'm getting when it tries to save:

### Errno::EPERM in PostsController#update

```
Operation not permitted - /usr/local/src/project_name/public/assets/
...
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:43:in `update'
```

I've chmod'ed the directories to 755, as suggested in an existing Stack Overflow solution. That shouldn't even matter though, because thin (my web server) is running as root (via sudo) so that I can bind to 443 (HTTPS). I don't understand why would there even be a permission error for root. What am I not getting? Is the file being uploaded by the user under an anonymous public account, or is the application server saving it as root?

## Additional info:

**Environment:** Development

**Operating System:** OS X 10.9.3

**Ruby version:**
MRI ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.4.0]

**Gem versions:**

```
Gems included by the bundle:
  * actionmailer (4.0.3)
  * actionpack (4.0.3)
  * activemodel (4.0.3)
  * activerecord (4.0.3)
  * activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
  * activesupport (4.0.3)
  * acts-as-taggable-on (3.2.6)
  * arel (4.0.2)
  * atomic (1.1.15)
  * bcrypt (3.1.7)
  * bcrypt-ruby (3.1.5)
  * builder (3.1.4)
  * bundler (1.5.3)
  * climate_control (0.0.3)
  * cocaine (0.5.3)
  * coffee-rails (4.0.1)
  * coffee-script (2.2.0)
  * coffee-script-source (1.7.0)
  * daemons (1.1.9)
  * epiceditor (0.2.2.1)
  * erubis (2.7.0)
  * eventmachine (1.0.3)
  * execjs (2.0.2)
  * faraday (0.9.0)
  * friendly_id (5.0.4)
  * haml (4.0.5)
  * haml-rails (0.5.3)
  * hike (1.2.3)
  * i18n (0.6.9)
  * jquery-rails (3.1.0)
  * json (1.8.1)
  * jwt (1.0.0)
  * mail (2.5.4)
  * mime-types (1.25.1)
  * minitest (4.7.5)
  * multi_json (1.8.4)
  * multi_xml (0.5.5)
  * multipart-post (2.0.0)
  * oauth (0.4.7)
  * oauth2 (0.9.4)
  * paperclip (4.1.1)
  * polyglot (0.3.4)
  * rack (1.5.2)
  * rack-test (0.6.2)
  * rails (4.0.3)
  * railties (4.0.3)
  * rake (10.1.1)
  * rdiscount (2.1.7.1)
  * sass (3.2.14)
  * sass-rails (4.0.1)
  * sorcery (0.8.5)
  * sprockets (2.11.0)
  * sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
  * sqlite3 (1.3.9)
  * thin (1.6.2)
  * thor (0.18.1)
  * thread_safe (0.2.0)
  * tilt (1.4.1)
  * treetop (1.4.15)
  * tzinfo (0.3.38)
  * uglifier (2.4.0)
```

**File permissions** (via *ls -la public*):

```
drwxr-xr-x   9 proto  admin   306 Jul  6 15:16 .
drwxr-xr-x  23 proto  admin   782 Mar 28 06:24 assets
```

**Server Daemon** (via *ps aux | grep [t]hin*):

```
root 2650 0.0 0.9 2513704 79120 ?? S 3:43PM 0:07.81 thin server (0.0.0.0:443)
```

**Post model**:

```ruby
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Relationships
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: [:slugged, :history]
  has_attached_file :photo,
    path: ':rails_root/public/assets/',
     url: ':basename.:extension'
  belongs_to :author
  # Validations
  validates_presence_of :title, :body, :author_id, :slug
  validates_uniqueness_of :slug
  validates_attachment_content_type :photo, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  # Overriding this friendly method to update slug when title changes
  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    slug.blank? || title_changed?
  end
end
```

**Update action**:

```ruby
def update
  @data = {
    title: params[:post][:title],
    body: params[:post][:body],
    photo: params[:post][:photo]
  }
  if @post.update! @data
    redirect_to @post
  else
    render :edit, layout: 'layouts/admin'
  end
end
```

**Form partial**:

```ruby
= form_for post, html: { multipart: true } do |f|
  = f.text_field :title, placeholder: 'Title'
  %br
  = f.text_area :body, class: 'hidden'
  #epiceditor
  %br
  = f.submit 'Save', class: 'button'
  - unless post.new_record?
    = link_to 'Delete', post, method: 'delete', class: 'button'
  = f.file_field :photo, class: 'upload'
- unless post.photo.nil?
  = link_to post.photo.url, post.photo.url
```

Comment: what is the output of `ps aux | grep rails`?

Comment: `proto 4226 0.2 0.0 2423368 176 s000 U+ 8:02PM 0:00.00 grep rails`

Answer (score 0):

Change the permissions on public folder to 775.

**Update**

You might find your solution here: [Errno::EPERM (Operation not permitted FILE_PATH) when uploading image with Rails, Carrierwave, Amazon EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19173194/errnoeperm-operation-not-permitted-file-path-when-uploading-image-with-rails)

Looks like you might need to change the owner of `public/assets` to root (or whichever user the application is running as).

Comment: I've changed the permissions to 775, but I get the same error.

Comment: That means it's not the public folder that's causing problems. Try changing permissions on tmp folder.

Comment: I set tmp to 777. Still the same error. Any more ideas?

Comment: May be it's not able to create assets folder. Please create the folder if it doesn't exist.

Comment: The public/assets folder exists, is not empty, and is set to 777 permissions.

Comment: Honestly, I am out of ideas :-(

Comment: It would appear that chown doesn't like root `chown: public: illegal user name`

Answer (score 0):

This is too long to write as a comment, but you could use other port than 443, which the root will redirect to from port 443, using, let's say, iptables.

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8443
```

Then you can start your server normally, as rails user, on port 8443

This is of course if you want to do so.

Regarding the comment/question I've asked to your question, I'm not familiar with thin server, but I would consider the case where the application is running as rails user (proton?) and the frontend web server as root. In that case, root owned assets folder will probably not writeable for rails user....

Comment: I don't have iptables on OS X, but ipfw might work. I'll give it a shot.